# How can I find last month records?

Tags: mysql

how can I found last month of records while from current month.

ex.

```
12-11-2015
12-12-2015
12-1-2016
12-2-2016
```

I wrote my query like this:

```
select * from tbl where  MONTH(date) < MONTH(CURDATE());
```

It shows only one record 12-1-2016. But I want all record except last record 12-2-2016.

I think problem with different years.

Comment: It's because month 11 is greater than month of current date.

Comment: And you store dates in `12-11-2015` format in DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE (MONTH(date) < MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())) 
      OR
      YEAR(date) < YEAR(CURDATE())
```

The predicates used in the above query essentially say: if both dates are on the same year, then you can compare month, otherwise you have to only compare the year value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl where  MONTH(date) < MONTH(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(date) < YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Comment: This is not correct I'm afraid. Think about this date `'2017-01-01'`. The month of this date is *less* than the month of the *current date*. And yet this date is *past* the current date.